# executing C++ code with params from shell

Tags: c++, shell, unix

This might be a very dumb question to ask.. 
But, Lets say I have a C++ code which runs like this from terminal

```
./sayhello --name=fraz

outputs 
Hello, fraz!
```

Now, I want to write a shell script which takes an input from the user in that shell and gives me the output.

How can I achieve this?
Any suggestions

Comment: Uhm, do you need a shell script or C++ code?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to shell script to invoke your C++ program? Or do you mean that you want your shell script to behave identically to your C++ program?

Comment: Hi, I want to write a shell script to invoke my C++ program.
Also.. what if the shell script and binaries are in different location

Comment: Please explain exactly how the shell script would be invoked and what it would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the name from standard input:

```
#!/bin/sh
read arg
./sayhello --name=$arg
```

Or, if you want to read the name from the shell script's command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
./sayhello --name=${1:-Rob}
```

---

You may need to specify the location of your `sayhello` binary:

```
/usr/local/bin/sayhello --name=${1:-Rob}
```

or

```
./binaries/linux/x86/sayhello --name=${1:-Rob}
```

Or even:

```
 PATH=/opt/my/path:${PATH}
 sayhello --name=${1:-Rob}
```

Comment: Hi,
  If my sayhello binary is different from where my shell script is.. 
Will ./path/to/sayhello --name${1:=Rob} still work?

Comment: Yes. For some more examples, see my recent edit.